# How to insert into table with 3 foreign keys in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project for school in MySQL and need to add 10 fields to each table that I've created. Here's a picture of my current schema:
[image: See picture below.]

The schema has been approved by my teacher and I'm starting to add fields to each table so that I can begin building triggers, views and other parts of the final project.

My issue is in attempting to add to the `order_line_items` field. As you can see, it contains 3 foreign keys and 1 primary key.

This query is giving me an error:

```
insert into order_line_items (line_item_id, line_item_description, line_item_quantity, orders_order_id, orders_vendors_vendor_id, products_product_id) values (1, 'syrup', 86, 6, 9, 6);
```

Here is the error code:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`order_line_items`, CONSTRAINT `fk_order_line_items_orders1` FOREIGN KEY (`orders_order_id`, `orders_vendors_vendor_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`order_id`, `vendors_vendor_id`) ON DELETE )

I've tried adding some select statements into the above statement, but then I usually get an error that the select statement cannot appear in this position, etc.

My question is, how can I add into the `order_line_items` table so that the above errors do not occur considering I would need to reference 3 separate tables in my select statement? What would be the easiest way to write this?

As a followup question, how would I add to my other tables with similar constraints such as recipes or `sales_has_products`? How can I reference 2-3 foreign keys in a single insert statement cleanly with this schema?

Comment: it's a foreign key. records have to exist in ALL of the parent tables before you can insert anything into the child tables. `show innodb table status` will have a "last foreign key error" section buried in it, and tell you exactly which FK relationship was violated.

Comment: The only parent table that does not currently have something in it is ingredients. I'll add some entities and see what it says.

Comment: `Ingredients` is not parent table in this case. Your problem is that in `order` table, there is no record with `order_id=6` and `vendors_vendor_id=9`

Comment: You should have just answered the question. I would have given you the best answer. I removed the FK on product_id (not needed) and made sure my order matched the orders vendor id and order id and it works now.